# WCF REST Service to Upload Image of Size 30 to 50 MB

Tags: c#, android, image, wcf, rest

I am planning to create a WCF REST Service to upload image from Any of the devices like Android,IOS, Windows Phone or a WEB Page.

Since The image size may is very High, what is the best approach to create service.
Moreover this service should be consumable to all the client mentioned above.

currently i used base64string conversion but it is failing in converting large size images.

can we use filestreams instead, it should HTML&javascript client also.

Answer (score 0):

Here is very good example of wcf rest api file upload.

[WCF REST WITH FILE UPLOAD](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/757991/File-Upload-using-WCF-REST-API-and-JavaScript)

You can use it through javascript ajax

android ( By using Multipart Entity Builder ) and other platforms also.